# Set multiple Alarms with multiple dates from a ArrayList

Tags: java, android, date, alarmmanager

In my Application i need to Start after Reboot all the Alarms that i have set befor by using the dates in my Arraylist class that i have saved by sharedprefs. But only the one is set by the Alarmmanager. I used a BroadcastReciver and a for loop.

```
ArrayList<DateList1> dateses;
Date dateFromLog;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("The Selected date", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("Date0list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<DateList1>>() {
    }.getType();
    dateses = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (dateses == null) {
        dateses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    AlarmManager alarmManager  = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    for (int i = 0; i<dateses.size(); i++){

        calendar.setTime(dateses.get(i).getDate1());

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);

        intentArray.add(pendingIntent);

    }






}











    }
```

And here is how i add the Date to the Arraylist

```
ArrayList<DateList1> Dates = new ArrayList<>();






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_picker);

    einfüGGen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    datums = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datums);
    fachs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fachs);
    themens = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.themens);
    GG = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.textView));








    einfüGGen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra("datum", datums.getText().toString());
            resultIntent.putExtra("fach", fachs.getText().toString());
            resultIntent.putExtra("themen", themens.getText().toString());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();

            int y = Dates.size();

            for (int i = 0; i<Dates.size(); i++){




                Toast.makeText(EingabeFeld.this,"SOOOOSSS"+y,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }






        }
    });



    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            Toast.makeText(EingabeFeld.this, "Die Erinnerung wurde festgelegt für den "+dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(year,month,dayOfMonth);
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,20);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);


            Date date = c.getTime();

            Dates.add(1,new DateList1(date));

            startAlarm(c);


            saveData();
```

Here is the actual class for the arraylist

```
public Date date1;


public DateList1(Date date){


    date1 = date;
}



public Date getDate1() {
    return date1;

}
```

}

I Hope this is going to see Someone and Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which one is set? The first in the list? Last? Random?

Comment: Also, your SharedPreferences name shouldn't have spaces.

Comment: Use set instead setExact ... and check your list size() ... and u should must new the ArrayList, top of codes

Comment: The first one of the list

Comment: I checked the size and i set 3 dates to the arraylist but it displays me that only one is in it

Answer (score 1):

I have Solved it :D.
I did the adding to the ArrayList and the saving part in my MainActivity,and got the long by the startActivityForResult Method to my MainActivity from my SecondActivity.

Thanks for those who tried to help me,i really like you guys and have a nice day with errorless Code ;D